# Java class instantiation clarification

Tags: java, class, field, instantiation

Given two .java files:

```
// Car.java
class Car {
    static int counter = 0; // Class field
    Car () { counter++;}
}
```

and

```
// Cars.java
public class Cars{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        System.out.println(Car.counter);  // Does this instantiate a Car?
    }
}
```

I'm learning Java, and I'm simply trying to be accurate (pedantic?) here.

Compiling, then executing `java Cars` yields the correct value of `0`. Since a Car hasn't been instantiated (or has it?), what would you say happens in this code?  I mean, I can see that Cars.class makes use of Car.class, but I can't form the correct sentence to describe why this worked.  How would you describe this concept of making a class field "come to life", as it were, to a novice?

Comment: Maybe I should clarify my question.  Ok, so I understand that no Car object will be instantiated.  And I further understand the difference between a class field and an instance field.  What I'm unclear about is that since no object was instantiated, how did a Car "come into existence" to return the value of `0`?   Maybe I'm just thinking too much about this.

Comment: `counter` is a *class variable*. You don't need an object to access a *class variable*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you have two files Car.java & Cars.java, corresponding to your given code.
Now, when you compile Cars.java, it will automatically also create Car.class along with Cars.class
In fact, this Car.class is needed to run the Cars.class program. If you delete the former and then try running the Cars program, you will get following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Car
        at Cars.main(Cars.java:3)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Car
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        ... 1 more
```

Notice the source of exception here

```
java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass
```

The Java Classloader is a part of the JRE that dynamically loads Java classes into the JVM. When a class is initialized, all static variable instances are placed on the heap. Since your Cars.class program makes a reference to a static variable of Car.class program, it loads it into the JVM too.

Note that loading is quite different from instantiating. The phrase "instantiating a class" means creating an "instance" of a class. To instantiate a class, we use the new operator as:

```
Car myCar = new Car();
```

The new operator instantiates a class by allocating memory for a new object and returning a reference to that memory. Here memory for instance variables will also be allocated dynamically (as needed). Note that each instance will be allocated a new memory space. However, they will still share the same statically allocated variables.

So, in your program, you are not *instantiating* the Car class, but you are still **loading** it into the JVM.

Comment: BINGO!!  This explanation solidifies my understanding.  THANK YOU!!

Answer (score 3):

No it won't. `Car.counter` is used to get the reference to the `counter` in `Car`.

The keyword `static` means that the field `counter` is something that belongs to the entire class and not to separate instances of an Object. The `counter` field therefore has the same value for all instances of `Car`.

Comment: Worth to mention about `static` modifier :)

Comment: @JorgeCampos, thanks for the tip, I elaborated a bit more on it ;)

Comment: This is a very good answer,albeit a tad off center of my question.Thanks Niels!

Answer (score 1):

From the [Oracle Docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html):

> Sometimes, you want to have variables that are common to all objects. This is accomplished with the `static` modifier. Fields that have the `static` modifier in their declaration are called *static fields* or *class variables*. They are associated with the class, rather than with any object. Every instance of the class shares a class variable, which is in one fixed location in memory. Any object can change the value of a class variable, but class variables can also be manipulated without creating an instance of the class.

So, to answer your question. NO - when accessing a static field you do **not** instantiate a class. The way you actually instantiate an object is by calling its [constructor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/constructors.html). Constructors are invoked by using the keyword `new` and the constructor name is the same as the class name.

```
Car c = new Car(); // instantiation via constructor
```

In order to describe your case:

> The `Cars` class uses a **class variable** from the `Car` class. Class variables are *associated* with the class and shared between every instance of the class.

Answer (score 0):

You are incrementing the counter in the Car consyructor.
This means that counter is incremented only when you create a new instance of Car using "new Car". The code does not instantiate any Car that is way counter is 0.

Answer (score 0):

Simply said:

You can consider classes as description of objects. Instances of a class are objects, that follow the rules of the description given in the class file.

But descriptions themselves can also be seen as objects that follow the rules of being a description. This objects are instances of the class `Class` - the description describing descriptions ;-) :

```
System.out.println(Car.class instanceof Class); // true
System.out.println(Class.class instanceof Class); // true
```

So you can see classes have representations (e.g. Car.class) and that representations can have fields and methods - the `static` ones.

Simply said ;-)

Answer (score 0):

static keyword means a single copy for the entire class, it does not belong to any specific instance of this class. static fields in a class is initialized by class initializer when your class is loaded into JVM for the first time.